# Hardy-littlewood maximal inequality for doubling measures

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, harmonic-analysis

I'm looking for references  discussing maximal (strong and weak) inequalities for doubling measure spaces.
More precisely,
Let $(X,\mu, d)$ be a metric measure space with $\mu$ being a doubling measure: 
What is known for the following maximal function:
$$ Mf(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{\mu(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f|d\mu$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an article written by Vagif S. Guliyev and Stefan G. Samko called "Maximal Operator in Variable Exponent Generalized Morrey Spaces on Quasi-metric Measure Space". In this paper, they prove theorems on the boundedness of the maximal operator that you mentioned.